# concatenate image and mask and make a 4-channel image and save image with 4 channels and read their path

Tags: python, pytorch, directory, path

I have a class for concatenating image and mask and make a 4-channel image in order to feed to improve_diffusion model (https://github.com/openai/improved-diffusion). I used the class and made a 4 channel images but when saving the image to use the image path, instead of 4-channel I have 3-channel image. how to save images with 4-channel and use their directory path.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import os
from natsort import natsorted
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io as img


class Image_Mask(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, img_dir, mask_dir, transform=None):

        
        self.images = natsorted(glob.glob(img_dir + "/*"))
        self.masks = natsorted(glob.glob(mask_dir + "/*"))

        self.imgs_and_masks = list(zip(self.images, self.masks))

        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):

        return len(self.imgs_and_masks)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        data = self.imgs_and_masks[idx]

        img_path = data[0] # image
        mask_path = data[1] # mask 


        img = np.array(Image.open(img_path))
        mask = np.array(Image.open(mask_path))[:,:,0:1] # take only one channel from mask
        #print(mask.shape)
        #print(mask.sum())

        sample = np.concatenate((img, mask), axis=2)
        sample = Image.fromarray(sample)
 
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
            
        return sample
```

for saving image and mask:

```
img_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/improved-diffusion/datasets/images"
mask_dir="/content/drive/MyDrive/improved-diffusion/datasets/masks"
output=Image_Mask(img_dir, mask_dir)
```

now I have 4 channels.

```
print(f"Image_Mask Shape {np.shape(output[0]), type(output[0])}")
```

Image_Mask Shape ((529, 622, 4), <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>)

but after saving I have 3 channels.

```
from  tqdm import tqdm
for i,img in tqdm(enumerate(output)):
  output_path = f'/content/drive/MyDrive/improved-diffusion/datasets/fourchannel/Image_mask_{i}.png'
  with open(output_path,'wb') as f:
    img.save(f)
```

```
import cv2
path='/content/drive/MyDrive/improved-diffusion/datasets/cju0qkwl35piu0993l0dewei2.jpg'
img= cv2.imread(path)
img.shape
```

`(529, 622, 3)`

I need 4 channels image directory_path

Comment: It seems you saved a PNG, but opened a JPEG?

Comment: Is your question really minimal [mcve]? Is the torch stuff necessary, or is a 4-channel image created like this enough to show the issue `im = np.random.randint((480,640,4), dtype=np.uint8)` ?

Comment: I need an image with 4-channel and with JPG format it is not possible to save it in this way also the only way to keep all channels I think is in PNG format. I think torch stuff is necessary as I need the image with the same structure for feeding to the network. I need to concatenate an image (3-channel) with a mask and save all the generated images as a 4-channel image.

Comment: So why are you opening a JPEG?

Comment: The format of my dataset is JPEG. I have two datasets. One image and one mask and all of them are in JPEG format. This is just for checking how many channels my images have.